# run python script from google home

Tags: dialogflow-es

I am trying to figure out if it is possible to trigger a python script to be run using google home? I would like to do something like saying "Hey Google run my python script." And from the Google home would execute running my python script. Anyone know if that is possible?

Answer (score 1):

You could create a Dialogflow app that integrates with the Google Assistant so that when you invoke the app it sends a HTTP request to your server.  You could setup your server so that it runs your Python script when you receive that HTTP request.

Tutorial to create a Dialogflow app: https://dialogflow.com/docs/getting-started/building-your-first-agent

Comment: OK but that python/php script runs on a local machine in your home? So you set up a reverse proxy server with nginx, right?

Answer (score 1):

I had to do this for my assistant as well. Here's what I did:

First I made a PHP script which wraps my Python script.
The code goes like this:

```
<?php
$resolved_query = $_POST['resolved_query'];
$keywords=shell_exec('/usr/bin/python <YOUR PYTHON FILE NAME>.py "'.$resolved_query.'"');
echo $keywords;
?>
```

Next I changed my Default Fallback Intent in dialogflow so that it uses webhook. You can see this option at the bottom of the page in Default Fallback Intent.

Now, in order for you to return the result from Python script, just print the result in your Python script. Like:

```
print result
```

Now, if your Python file executes successfully, the result will be stored in *$keywords*. Just print that out and your response will be back at dialogflow.

This is basically how you can get your Python script to be run by dialogflow.

Comment: OK but that python/php script runs on a local machine in your home?  So you set up a reverse proxy server with nginx, right?

Comment: No. The script was hosted on aws. The python script was triggered through my webhoook.